# remove consecutive duplicate products in an Array of object and sum their quantity in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The array contains a list with products that are consecutive duplicated. I need to remove the consecutive duplicate products in the array and sum their quantities.

In this list of objects we have four values of `(D)` and two values of `(U)`. If the values are repeated and consecutive, I want to remove prev value and sum qty in last duplicate  value.

```
let books = [
  { id: "1", type: "D", price: 25, qty: 27},// *
  { id: "2", type: "D", price: 22, qty: 75},// *
  { id: "3", type: "D", price: 21, qty: 19},// *
  { id: "4", type: "D", price: 19, qty: 62},

  { id: "5", type: "U", price: 23, qty: 19},
  { id: "6", type: "D", price: 20, qty: 22},

  { id: "7", type: "U", price: 25, qty: 14},// *
  { id: "8", type: "U", price: 29, qty: 14}
]
```

The result will be like this:

```
[
  { id: "4", type: "D", price: 19, qty: 121},
  { id: "5", type: "U", price: 23, qty: 19},
  { id: "6", type: "D", price: 20, qty: 22},
  { id: "8", type: "U", price: 29, qty: 28}
]
```

and Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the array while looking ahead of 1 book and check whether it's of the same type as the current one. Sum `qty` accordingly.

Btw you have an error in your output, the first sum should be `183`, you missed the last book in the series.

```js
let books = [
  { id: "1", type: "D", price: 25, qty: 27},// *
  { id: "2", type: "D", price: 22, qty: 75},// *
  { id: "3", type: "D", price: 21, qty: 19},// *
  { id: "4", type: "D", price: 19, qty: 62},

  { id: "5", type: "U", price: 23, qty: 19},
  { id: "6", type: "D", price: 20, qty: 22},

  { id: "7", type: "U", price: 25, qty: 14},// *
  { id: "8", type: "U", price: 29, qty: 14}
];

const result = books.reduce((r, book, i, arr) => {
  if(arr[i+1]?.type === book.type){
    r.qty += book.qty;
  } else {
    r.arr.push({...book, qty: r.qty + book.qty});
    r.qty = 0;
  }
  return r;
}, {arr:[],qty:0}).arr;

result.forEach(r=>console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

Comment: Alexander Nenashev, thank you very much for help, and your effort.